# Pressing the quote button destroys text in code fences

Tags: bug, code-formatting, editor

Let's say I want to quote this shell code in a post:

```sh
foo=bar
echo $foo
```

First I put it in code fences so it shows up as code:

````markdown
```sh
foo=bar
echo $foo
```
````

Then to quote it, I select it and either press the **Blockquote** button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, but the newlines get converted to spaces, destroying it:

````markdown
> ```sh foo=bar echo $foo ```
````

I would expect it to output this:

````markdown
> ```sh
> foo=bar
> echo $foo
> ```
````

Which renders as:

> ```sh
> foo=bar
> echo $foo
> ```

This issue does not affect text indented by four spaces.

### Workaround

Use `<blockquote>`, though the start tag requires an extra newline, like this:

````markdown
<blockquote>

```sh
foo=bar
echo $foo
```
</blockquote>
````

Which renders as:

> ```sh
> foo=bar
> echo $foo
> ```

As an added bonus, this usually results in a smaller diff when editing, since the quote button rewraps text, but this doesn't of course.

### Also affects

#### Quoting text in HTML tags

For example, `<pre>`:

```markdown
<pre>
foo
bar
</pre>
```

becomes:

```markdown
> <pre> foo bar </pre>
```

#### Putting code fences into a list (bulleted or numbered)

````markdown
List this

```
foo
bar
```
````

becomes:

````markdown
 - List this
   
   ``` foo bar ```
````

or

````markdown
 3. List this
    
    ``` foo bar ```
````

### Context

I noticed this while [adding content to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56828523/revisions#rev-body-4e3709c0-d443-43b8-acc2-1ef7a8d27f12) and experienced the same problem while [quoting the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69791052/revisions#rev-body-49419ee9-e8a1-42b9-bd13-9f46732ee12a).

Comment: You can use indentation instead of code fences as a workaround.  I mean Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+Q.

Comment: But please dont ise a code fence on an already indented post.

Comment: Can I quote you on your code snippet demonstrating a quoted code snippet?

Comment: @Dave Sure but you'll have to put it in a quoted code snippet :P

Comment: This is still broken.